# Finding number of common divisors of two numbers in a combinatorial way

Tags: combinatorics

Given two numbers, how can we find the number of common divisors in a combinatorial way? What I immediately thought about is finding their prime factors, but I have thought for a lot of time and have figured out no way of going out from there!

For example:

$363,825=3\times 3\times 3\times 5\times 5\times 7\times 7\times 11$

$35,700=2\times 2\times 3\times 5\times 5\times 7\times 17$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=p_{1}^{r_1}\ldots p_{n}^{r_n}$ and $b=p_{1}^{s_1}\ldots p_{n}^{s_n}$. Then $\gcd (a,b)=p_{1}^{t_1}\ldots p_{n}^{t_n}$ where $t_i=\min (r_i,s_i)$. Now $x$ divides $a$ and $x$ divides $b$ if and only if $x$ divides $\gcd (a,b)$, so the number of common divisors of $a$ and $b$ is the number of divisors of $\gcd (a,b)$, which is $(t_1+1)\ldots (t_n+1)$.

Comment: In the two numbers, 2 is a prime factor in 35,700 but it is not in 363,825, how would I calculate GCD?

Comment: Yes, indeed, but do I calculate it also in the formula (t1+1)...(tn+1)?

Comment: Oh, I feel dumb now.
Thanks alot for your thorough explanation and help!

Comment: One more thing. the formula (t0+1)..(tn+1) can be used for any number to calculate how many divisors it has, given that it is written as a primes factorial. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the number of positive divisors of a positive integer is well known, and it requires factorization. So your number is the number of positive divisors of the greatest common divisor of your two numbers. Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer!